# HTML/JS- Opening an URL connection to a local host website to parse JSON payload

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, url

I have a HTML website, and I'm using a Localhost URL that contains JSON payload.

I know that I need to append user input (such as first name, last name, etc) to the URL, to open a URL connection to that URL, retrieve the JSON payload, then parse it and output it on my website. However, I'm unsure how to open the URL connection in HTML or JavaScript...

Comment: I don't know why someone voted you up. This question is unclear. You just want a JSON file?

Comment: I'm trying to open an URL connection to an Localhost website. That website contains JSON payload. I know how to parse the Payload, but I dont know how to open an URL connection using HTML or JS- Ive only done this with Java @PHPglue

Comment: [open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)? You can leave of `window` if you want. Of course, if you're on a web page and you just want to do stuff to it then just use a `<script>` tag.